# Raspberry Pi: Canon Camera disconnected after an unusing time

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi, libgphoto2

I have a Canon 5DS IV, connect to a RPi 3 Model B+ via USB port. I am using gphoto2 to capture photo.

Problem is:

- after around 5-6 hours not in use but camera + Pi are still on, camera disconnects to the Pi,
- I run `lsusb`, it return nothing about Canon camera.
- I run `gphoto2 --auto-detect`, it returns 'Error: No camera found'
- I turn off and on the camera again, run `lsusb`, the camera is detected as normal

My question:

Why did camera disconnect to Pi after a time?

And is there any way to keep camera live on until switch it off?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Might want to put this on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ to find more people who could answer this

Comment: thanks, I opened a question on that forum